# Problems with Python 3.9 installation

Tags: python, installation, pip, zlib, python-3.9

I'm quite new to all of this programming universe. I recently installed the latest version of python (3.9.1 from a tar.gz) so I configured vscode to use that one, when I run any scripts in it without debugging, it shows the following error in the last line of Traceback:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I just ignored it because I realized that when I change to pyhton 3.9 vs code shows a message "Linter pylint is not installed" excepting to fix the problem I select install but then it tells me that pip module is not builtin in python 3.9, I run in the python interpreter:

```
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I run the same script in other python interpreter (3.8) that came with the OS without any issues. Then I decided to install pip with the get-pip.py method BUT then it tells me that zlib module is not there:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

If I run get-pip.py with python3.8 and it completes the task successfully.

Can somebody guide me? I'm feeling like giving up and just use python3.8 but I really wanna overcome this issue. For some reason that I don't understand my python 3.9 installation seems to be messed up and I followed the readme instructions.

PD: I use Linux Mint 20.1

Comment: What is the content of the Python script you used for testing? Usually, after installing Python, it will come with the "pip" installation tool. Therefore, it is recommended that you reinstall "Python3.9" from this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: I just ran in the python interpreter `import pip`, with the intention of running `help(pip)` afterwards. I did install python 3.9 from the file that its provided in the official website, just to tried to reinstall it as you said and it worked wonderfully! It would have never crossed my mind that it would be so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled python with the file provided by the website in this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/) as suggested in the comments.